# Posting data via cURL throws an APPEND_SLASH error

Tags: django, rest, http, curl

I'd like to post data to an endpoint hosted by Django. I am using cURL in my terminal to do this:

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/bucket/create/ --data '{"name":"test2", "description":"hey"}'
```

But this throws the following error:

> RuntimeError at /bucket/create You called this URL via POST, but the
> URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't
> redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your
> form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/bucket/create/ (note the trailing
> slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.

As you can see I've added a slash to the URL in my request and am not sure why this is happening. It doesn't work without the slash either.

my project's URL related configurations:

- `ROOT_URLCONF = 'bucket_list.urls'`
- `urls.py`:

```py
#URLConf module
app_name = 'bucket'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>/', views.read_bucket),
    path('create/', views.create_bucket)
]
```

I also tried appending '?' at the end of 'create/'. Doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your URLconf?

Comment: @NickODell edited, let me know if that helps